# Android actionbar items remain when popping fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the support actionbar.  I'm also using fragments.  Typically, I change the fragment using navigation drawer and everything works fine.  Each fragment is able to make changes to the action bar items.  When I change to a new fragment, the changes (new buttons) are removed.

Here's my problem.  In one instance, I replace the fragment and add the existing fragment to the back stack.  When I go back to the previous fragment, the actionbar still has the items from the previous fragment.

Example:
1) Fragment 1 loads fragment 2 and places fragment 1 on the back stack
2) Fragment 2 places several new buttons in the actionbar
3) Fragment 2 exits and now I see the actionbar items from fragment 1 & 2

I do the same basic thing with 2 other fragments in a different location and don't have the same problem.  The only difference I can figure out between the two implementations is the way the 2nd fragments interact with the actionbar.

In the working case, fragment 2 load items inflating a menu in onCreateMenuOptions.  This works well.

In the NOT working case, fragment 2 does NOT inflate a menu but uses a custom view:

```
         // Set action bar custom view and display options.
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_viewer);
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg));
```

This is the only difference I can find. Am I missing something?  (Obviously)  But the question is what???

The code used to load the fragment 2 from fragment 1 is:

```
 MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

                        // Load the PDF fragment
                        MINPDFTronFragment fragment = new MINPDFTronFragment();
                        fragment.albumItem = albumItem;
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
```

The onCreate code used for fragment 2 is:

```
     // ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onCreate
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().supportRequestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

NEW EDITS:

These are the two methods that are doing the work on the action bar.  The first section here is the code for Fragment 1.  Fragment 1 is the fragment that launches Fragment 2 and places itself on the backstack:

```
     // ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onCreateOptionsMenu
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    mMenu = menu;

    // Inflate GridView menu
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.gridview_combined_menu, menu);

    // Gridview share menu
    MenuItem shareMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.MenuItemShare);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareMenuItem);
    setGridViewShareIntent(null); // TODO is this needed?

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


// ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onPrepareOptionsMenu
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    setOptionMenuItems();
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here are the same methods in Fragment 2 (the fragment launched by Fragment 1:

```
     // ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onCreateOptionsMenu
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    mMenu = menu;
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


// ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onPrepareOptionsMenu
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MINMainActivity MINMainActivity = (MINMainActivity) getActivity();
    boolean drawerIsOpen = MINMainActivity.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(MINMainActivity.mDrawerList);

    if(drawerIsOpen)
    {
    }

    else
    {
        }
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

As you can see, Fragment 2 isn't making mods in those methods.  Below is the code in Fragment 2 that manipulates the actionbar:

```
     // ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  onCreateView
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    initViewerLayout(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
 }
     // ***************************************************************************************************
//
//  initViewerLayout
//
// ***************************************************************************************************
private void initViewerLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Initialize the library
    try
    {
        PDFNet.initialize(MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance(), R.raw.pdfnet);
    }
    catch (PDFNetException e)
    {
        // Do something...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Inflate the view and get a reference to PDFViewCtrl
    pageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_viewer, container, false);

    // Set action bar custom view and display options.
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_viewer);
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
    MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg));

    // Initialize action bar buttons (we are using a custom view, so we
    // need to set click listeners for each item.
    mButtonViewMode = (ImageButton) MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ab_action_viewmode);
    mButtonViewMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewModePickerDialogFragment dialog = new ViewModePickerDialogFragment();
            dialog.mListener = MINPDFTronFragment.this;
            dialog.show(MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportFragmentManager(), "view_mode_picker");
            stopHideToolbarsTimer();
        }
    });
    updateButtonViewModeIcon();

    mButtonOutline = (ImageButton) MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ab_action_outline);
    mButtonOutline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Creates the dialog in full screen mode
            mBookmarksDialog = new BookmarksDialogFragment(mPdfViewCtrl, mBookmarkDialogCurrentTab);
            mBookmarksDialog.setBookmarksDialogFragmentListener(MINPDFTronFragment.this);
            mBookmarksDialog.mOutlineDialogFragmentListener = MINPDFTronFragment.this;
            mBookmarksDialog.mAnnotationDialogFragmentListener = MINPDFTronFragment.this;
            mBookmarksDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
            mBookmarksDialog.show(fragmentManager, "bookmarks_dialog");

            stopHideToolbarsTimer();

            // Example of how to show the OutlineDialogFragment as a dialog
            //OutlineDialogFragment outlineDialogFragment = new OutlineDialogFragment(mPdfViewCtrl);
            //outlineDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
            //outlineDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "outline_dialog");

            // Example of how to show the AnnotationDialogFragment as a dialog
            //AnnotationDialogFragment annotDialog = new AnnotationDialogFragment(mPdfViewCtrl);
            //annotDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_Base_AppCompat_Light);
            //annotDialog.show(fragmentManager, "annotation_dialog");
        }
    });

    mSearchView = (SearchView) MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ab_action_search);
    mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    mSearchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    // Let's get the internal button of the search view widget to change some properties.
    ImageView searchButton = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchButton.setBackgroundDrawable(mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.controls_annotation_toolbar_tool_bg));
    searchButton.setImageDrawable(mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view;
            if (searchView.isIconfiedByDefault() && !searchView.isIconified()) {
                AnalyticsHandler.getInstance().sendEvent("[Viewer] Find Text clicked");

                // Search has expanded
                startSearchMode();
            }
        }
    });
    mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            exitSearchMode();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mButtonAnnotToolbar = (ImageButton) MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ab_action_tools);
    mButtonAnnotToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAnnotationToolbar = new AnnotationToolbar(MINApplication.getAppContext(), pageView, mToolManager);
            mAnnotationToolbar.setButtonStayDown(SettingsManager.getContinuousAnnotationEdit(MINApplication.getAppContext()));

            if (SettingsManager.getContinuousAnnotationEdit(MINApplication.getAppContext())) {
                AnalyticsHandler.getInstance().sendEvent("[General] Continuous Annotation Edit enabled");
            }

            mAnnotationToolbar.show();

            AnalyticsHandler.getInstance().sendEvent("[Annotation Toolbar] Annotation Toolbar opened");
        }
    });

    mButtonShare = (ImageButton) MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.ab_action_share);
    mButtonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (MiscUtils.isKitKat()) {
                // If KitKat or higher, we show the Share/Print option
                SharePickerDialogFragment dialog = new SharePickerDialogFragment();
                dialog.mListener = MINPDFTronFragment.this;
                dialog.show(MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportFragmentManager(), "share_mode_picker");
            } else {
                MiscUtils.sharePdfFile(MINApplication.getAppContext(), albumItem);
                AnalyticsHandler.getInstance().sendEvent("[Viewer] Share clicked");
            }
        }
    });

    // Search prev/next buttons.
    mButtonSearchNext = (ImageButton) pageView.findViewById(R.id.floating_button_next);
    mButtonSearchNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearchUp = false;
            findText();
        }
    });
    mButtonSearchPrev = (ImageButton) pageView.findViewById(R.id.floating_button_prev);
    mButtonSearchPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearchUp = true;
            findText();
        }
    });

    // PDFViewCtrl settings
    mPdfViewCtrl = (CompleteReaderPDFViewCtrl) pageView.findViewById(R.id.pdfviewctrl);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setUrlExtraction(true);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setupThumbnails(true, true, true, 0, 50 * 1024 * 1024, 0.1);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setPageViewMode(PDFViewCtrl.PAGE_VIEW_FIT_PAGE);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setPageRefViewMode(PDFViewCtrl.PAGE_VIEW_FIT_PAGE);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setHighlightFields(true);
    mPdfViewCtrl.setZoomLimits(PDFViewCtrl.ZOOM_LIMIT_RELATIVE, 1.0, 20.0);
    updateViewMode();

    mSeekBar = (ThumbnailSlider) pageView.findViewById(R.id.thumbseekbar);
    // We pass a reference of the PDFViewCtrl to the slider so it can
    // interact with it (know number of pages, change pages, get thumbnails...
    // At this point no doc is set and the slider has no enough data
    // to initialize itself. When a doc is set we need to reset its data.
    mSeekBar.setPDFViewCtrl(mPdfViewCtrl);

    mPageNumberIndicator = (TextView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.page_number_indicator_current_page);

    mSearchProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mSearchProgressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.search_in_progress));
    mSearchProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mSearchProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mSearchProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mPdfViewCtrl.cancelFindText();
        }
    });

    mDownloadDocumentDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mDownloadDocumentDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.download_in_progress_message));
    mDownloadDocumentDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mDownloadDocumentDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDownloadDocumentDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Toast.makeText(MINApplication.getAppContext(), R.string.download_cancelled_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //TODO finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) in `onResume` of your 1 fragment.

EDIT:

If custom actionbar was set in fragment 2, you'll need to disable it in your first fragment (for example, in `onResume()`):

```
MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(Act‌​ionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
```

Comment: I tried this already but it was a good idea.  Personally, I believe that this should work and I'm not sure why it isn't.  Somehow it's retaining those buttons even when you invalidate the options menu.  I don't know how since supportInvalidateOptionsMenu should clear everything out.  If the buttons are being re-added in some way even though we are not re-loading Fragment 2, it points to the way Fragment 2 is initializing the options menu in the first place.  I keep thinking it must have something to do withe ".setCustomView"

Comment: any chances you have a wrong instance of Context with your `getSharedInstance()` method?

Comment: I'm using the same context throughout the app.  So, I don't think that's the problem.  How would I check?

Comment: Maybe you should call `MINMainActivity.getSharedInstance().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);` in 1 fragment's `onResume()`? i.e. disable custom view

Answer (score 0):

Here's my problem. In one instance, I replace the fragment and add the existing fragment to the back stack. When I go back to the previous fragment, the actionbar still has the items from the previous fragment.
Where you are call method that change your actionbar with new buttons? if you call it in fragment onCreate() it will not invoked. try to call it from fragment onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState).

take a look on fragment lifecycle methods
[image: Fragment lifecycle methods]

Comment: All the work in done in 2 following methods.  I'll modify my question above with the methods from Fragment 1 (the fragment launching Fragment 2) and Fragment 2 (the fragment launched by Fragment 1).