# Have to manually clear options menu on every fragment

Tags: android, android-menu, android-architecture-navigation

I have options menu on some fragments, but the case here is the lastly opened option menu keep appearing in fragment where there is no any option menu, if there is a option menu in next fragment both lastly opened option menu items and current fragment option menu items appear in the current fragment.

current solution I have is

```
// in fragments that have options menu
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.clear()
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu)
}

// in fragment where there is no options menu
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        menu.clear()
}
```

I even tried following in fragments that have options menu,but not working

```
 override fun onOptionsMenuClosed(menu: Menu) {
        menu.clear()
 }
```

Having to override `onCreate` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` on every fragment that do not have a option menu is not a good solution. I have lots of fragments (I am using single activity pattern with navigation architecture component). **How could I solve this problem in a better way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a a `BaseFragment` class and overide your `onCreate()` in it.
So you will be able to extend every `YourFragment` with `BaseFragment`

Also you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in your `onCreate()`

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) to documentation

Comment: While this will work, I wonder why this is happening in the first place?

Comment: @user158 Here is some workaround on your problem. I think it explains and solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836416/android-actionbar-items-remain-when-popping-fragment

Answer (score 2):

Even though I did what Anton suggested, even with that options menu started showing up and menu items started duplicating. So filed an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142089710) in issuetracker. They helped me to figure out the issue.

The reason was I was using ViewPager2 and I was passing wrong `FragmentManager`  to `PagerAdapter`'s constructor

```
// instead of
pager.adapter = PagerAdapter(activity!!)
class PagerAdapter(fa:FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

// pass container of the ViewPager2 to the PagerAdapter's constructor
// use Fragment as the FragmentManager since ViewPager2 is inside a Fragment
pager.adapter = PagerAdapter(this)
class PagerAdapter(f:Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(f) {
```